# How to search for XML elements in python?

Tags: python, soap

Сode that is shown below works perfectly, but the problem is that i need to manually set name-spaces like `d:`. Is it possible somehow to search for elements ignoring this name-spaces like `dom.getElementsByTagName('Scopes')`?

```
def parseSoapBody(soap_data):
    dom = parseString(soap_data)

    return {
        'scopes': dom.getElementsByTagName('d:Scopes')[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
        'address': dom.getElementsByTagName('d:XAddrs')[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code uses parseString and `getElementsByTagName`, I'm assuming you are using minidom. In that case, try:

```
dom.getElementsByTagNameNS('*', 'Scopes')
```

---

It doesn't say so in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Document.getElementsByTagNameNS), but if you look in the source code for `xml/dom/minidom.py`, you'll see `getElementsByTagNameNS` calls `_get_elements_by_tagName_ns_helper` which is defined like this:

```
def _get_elements_by_tagName_ns_helper(parent, nsURI, localName, rc):
    for node in parent.childNodes:
        if node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            if ((localName == "*" or node.localName == localName) and
                (nsURI == "*" or node.namespaceURI == nsURI)):
                rc.append(node)
            _get_elements_by_tagName_ns_helper(node, nsURI, localName, rc)
    return rc
```

Notice that when `nsURI` equals `*`, only the `localName` needs to match.

---

For example,

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
content = '''<root xmlns:f="foo"><f:test/><f:test/></root>'''
dom = minidom.parseString(content)
for n in dom.getElementsByTagNameNS('*', 'test'):
    print(n.toxml())
    # <f:test/>
    # <f:test/>
```